# How to filter in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, filter, filtering

First of all i am very new to Symfony 2 and started to learn.

Is there any possibility for filter a value? Perhaps filter chains too?
I know this concept from Zend Framework 1 and 2.

E.g.:

- i have a string "1A- N "
- now i want to filter so that only numeric values pass; result "1"

Do i have to implement this on my own i Symfony?

I would like to do something like:

```
$text = '1A - N';
$numberFilter = new NumberFilter();
$filteredText = $numberFilter->filter($text);
//now in $text i find '1'
```

But for now i nowhere found something like this in Symfony what surprises me a lot. I thought it is a full stack framework and such function is so basic.

I found something like validators but they only say if a value e.g. contains only numbers or not. Or is the validation concept of symfony like that it does not only say if it is numeric or not but filter all other smybols out, too?

Comment: I'm not sure I udnerstood the question: are you looking for filter function alread existing in Symfony or the way to _create_ a filter function with Symfony? In the latter case, you could use a "Service". Do you know how it works?

Comment: Maybe Data Transformers? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html Like @tomazahlin, I don't see the need for what you described.  Perhaps you could be more specific as to why you need filters or perhaps link to the ZF2 documentation?

Comment: @Blacksad; Yes i look for a existing function in Symfony. 
@Cerad: Example: user input " 1 234" and i need only the numbers (postal code)

I for now only evaluating Symfony:-)

Comment: @Cerad: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.filter.set.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the answers and searching i got to the following conclusion.
There is no concept for this for now in Symphony 2.
You have to write it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want precisely:

- disallow user input not fulfilling certain rules

  - use validators in forms
  - use asserts in entities
- chenge user input in case it's wrong

  - use viewransformers in forms
  - use event listeners in forms
  - use event listeners for doctrine
- change data that already exists in the database

  - use filters in twig
  - create a command to execute from commandline

You can also try http://php.net/manual/ro/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Comment: Ok thanks for the Info, but it seems that there is no given funcionality i can use. Like i see i have to implement it on my own and than integrate it "Change user input in case it's wrong"

Comment: Looking at zend filters, you have those in twig, filter like your "numberfilter" is neither preset in zend nor in symfony/twig, for a good reason

Comment: Look here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.filter.set.html Many filters there:-)

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.filter.set.html#digits to be more precise)

Comment: yup, missed this, it comes with php itself though 
http://php.net/manual/ro/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Answer (score 0):

I have built quite big apps with Symfony and never needed such a feature. Filters are mostly used in views anyway. Symfony comes with Twig, which has filters, that can be chained, and you can write your own filters. But if you need filters in the backend to do some background processing, you can accomplish it the way you suggested.

I suggest you write an interface and use a factory pattern, so you set a standard if you make many filters, so it will be easier to make the chaining work;)

Comment: Interface for sure;-), but why the factory pattern and which one abstract factory or factory method this is do not understand why?

Comment: Why factory? So you can do something like this: $filteredText = $textHolder->setText('text')->filter('first)->filter('second')->getText();

Comment: Sry i do not get it. "$textHolder() = 'text';" is syntactically wrong; will not work :-( "$textHolder->filter('first)->filter('second')->getText();" is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface pattern :-)

I think you want to create filter objects in the filter()-method, right?

Comment: Hey, you have probably seen the old comment, I had some typos while writing. Ofcourse, the Fluent pattern is the base, where you will have return $this; Use the factory pattern to distinguish between the various filters. For example when you will call ->filter('first) the factory class will return and instance of the FirstFilter and process the text, and then you can apply another filter... etc, and at the end you get the text by getText().